# Unable to get value from a nested Perl Hash Structure

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I've scoured the internet for guidance and have been working on this for days but cannot understand the data structure. I have a multilevel hash structure with nested arrays as well. It looks something like this

```
{'Suggestion' => {
     'Car' => {'Make' => ['Toyota'] }, 
     'Bike' => 'Giant', 
     'Motorcycle' => {'Make'=> ['BMW']}
};
```

I can extract `Toyota` and `BMW` to a string variable with `{"Suggestion"}->{"Car"}->{"Make"} and {"Suggestion"}->{"Motorcycle"}->{"Make"}`.

when I try to extract `Giant` using `{"Suggestion"}->{"Bike"}`, it gives me a HASH reference as a string (`HASH(9879)`). When I use `Dumper({"Suggestion"}->{"Bike"})`, it gives me `$VAR = {'Bike' => undef};`. So its a Hash with a key and undef value?

Then if I try to deference it using `%({"Suggestion"}->{'Bike'})`, it gives me an error:

```
Can't use string ("Bike") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at (eval 7552). So this is telling me that I'm trying to use a string that I want as a hash ref?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your hashref in a variable?

Comment: No. I'm using it as I've shown above within a loop to create a long string by using join().

Comment: In your code `print Dumper($var)` and post output, where `$var` what holds `Suggestion`. Note: the posted in message structure has unbalanced curly bracket.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you have a hashref at all. Please show more code.

Comment: What you show above is fine, and works just fine.   There's got to be _something_ different in your actual code? Can you post a minimal runnable example of what fails?

Comment: Re "_No. I'm using it as I've shown above within a loop to create a long string by using join()_" --- wait, that's not in a variable at all? How do you expect to use it then?

Answer (score 1):

Provided by OP sample code is not complete and curly brackets are unbalanced.

Bellow code snippet demonstrates that if data structure is complete there should be no any error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = {
    'Suggestion' => {
         'Car' => {'Make' => ['Toyota'] },
         'Bike' => 'Giant',
         'Motorcycle' => {'Make'=> ['BMW']}
    }
};

say Dumper($data);

say 'Bike: ' . $data->{Suggestion}{Bike};
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Suggestion' => {
                            'Bike' => 'Giant',
                            'Car' => {
                                       'Make' => [
                                                   'Toyota'
                                                 ]
                                     },
                            'Motorcycle' => {
                                              'Make' => [
                                                          'BMW'
                                                        ]
                                            }
                          }
        };

Bike: Giant
```

Sample to generate multiline string

```
my $trafficStr = "
Bike:       $Transport->{"Suggestion"}{"Bike"}
Car:        $Transport->{"Suggestion"}{"Car"}{"Make"}[0]
Motorcycle: $Transport->{"Suggestion"}{"Motorcycle"}{"Make"}[0]
";
```

Comment: Thanks for balancing the Bracket. It was a typo.

Comment: @user2127579 To avoid such situation use 'Copy+Paste` approach to minimize errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the data structure as an input.
$Transport

This was the code snippet I was working with and is the final correct answer:

```
my $trafficStr = "";
$trafficStr .= "Bike: " . $Transport->{"Suggestion"}->{"Bike"} . "\n";
$trafficStr .= "Car: " . join(',' , @{$Transport->{"Suggestion"}->{"Car"}->{"Make"}}) . "\n" ;
$trafficStr .= "Motorcycle: " . join(',' , @{$Transport->{"Suggestion"}->{"Motorcycle"}->{"Make"}}) . "\n";
return $trafficStr;`
```

This will return:

```
Bike: Giant
Car: Toyota
Motorcycle: BMW
```

These were the **WRONG** ways to get `Giant`.

```
$trafficStr .= "Bike: " . join(',' , %{$Transport->{"Suggestion"}->{"Bike"}}) . "\n";
Commit failed: Can't use string ("Giant") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at (eval 7552)
```

```
$trafficStr .= "Bike: " . join(',' , Dumper({$Transport->{"Suggestion"}->{"Bike"}})) . "\n";
Bike: $VAR1 = {'Bike'=>Undef}
```

```
$trafficStr .= "Bike: " . join(',' , $Transport->{"Suggestion"}->{"Bike"}) . "\n";
Bike: HASH(0x9f35c98)
```

Comment: You should edit your question with the actual code that was not working. Otherwise, this answer is worthless to anyone but you.

Comment: Hmm, why you use `join()` if you know that array has only one element? You could use array index `$Transport->{"Suggestion"}{"Car"}{"Make"}[0]` instead. I do not see how a car can have several manufacturers (of cause if you do not plan to include every manufacturer of components from which the car is assembled).

Comment: Note: to build `$trafficStr` the way you do is to clutter the code, it is very difficult to read. Instead you can do `my $trafficStr = "some line1(Enter) some line2(Enter)some line3" . {code} . "[Enter]some line3[Enter]". This way it looks like it will be printed with substituted variables with stored values and allows to embed piece of code which produces some string. Try it just for experiment and perhaps you will never go back to old ways.

Comment: Please see the bottom part of my answer with demonstration how you can build multiline string variable.